# maven repository eclipse project

Tags: maven, repository, tapestry

A quick question.
A am new to pom repositories.

I added this

```xml
<repository>
  <id>tapx</id>
  <name>howard lewisship snapshot repository</name>
  <url>http://howardlewisship.com/snapshot-repository/</url>
</repository>
```

to pom file to get these files for tapestry project.

sha1 left and filename ont the right

```
7155233ba0dfbd99e19358f57e262ad484a440c6  tapx-core-1.1-20110620.210912-27.jar
822c300e6b6d93c53216d8d4fbb9b13217a7fb84  tapx-core-1.2-20110705.222421-4.jar
c11b3134128c3267f55dc4f8bfaab2f1f68ba711  tapx-datefield-1.1-20110617.214353-17.jar
ba2f05929baf2c01d22300953e983ac7a8f791b5  tapx-datefield-1.2-20110705.222544-4.jar
```

rebuild the index for added project repository
in eclipse when i enter sha1sum on the dependency searcher in eclipse i get 0 results.

Please tell me what i did wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Enable snapshots](http://maven.apache.org/pom.html#Repositories); IIRC they're disabled by default.

```xml
<repository>
  <id>tapx</id>
  <name>howard lewisship snapshot repository</name>
  <url>http://howardlewisship.com/snapshot-repository/</url>

  <snapshots>
    <enabled>true</enabled>
    <updatePolicy>never</updatePolicy>
    <checksumPolicy>fail</checksumPolicy>
  </snapshots>
</repository>
```

[Also see this super-POM reference info.](http://www.sonatype.com/books/mvnref-book/reference/pom-relationships-sect-pom.html#pom-relationships-sect-super-pom)

Comment: I am still getting 0, but this helped a lot.