# Where to define "repositories" in eclipse project

Tags: android, eclipse, maven, cocos2d-x

I'm following a tutorial to integrate facebook sdk in my android project, I'm using eclipse currently , tutorial is asking me to define `repositories { mavenCentral() }` in build.gradle file , but I don't know in which file I've to add this in eclipse... `ant.properties, project.properties` or any other file?

[image]

I've read some related threads , but I could not find in which file I've to change.

> [Defining Repository in Maven](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15410454/defining-repository-in-maven)
>
> [maven repository eclipse project](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12438607/maven-repository-eclipse-project)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are working in Eclipse and the tutorial asks you to add the Maven central to your Gradle configuration which you (properly) don't have in Eclipse.
You basically have two options:

1. Get a Gradle plugin for Eclipse (like this: http://marketplace.eclipse.org/content/gradle-integration-eclipse-44)
2. Get Android Studio (http://developer.android.com/tools/studio/index.html), where Gradle is already an integrated part of the IDE.

Both options means that you have to get your head around what Gradle does, and how it works, but it'll properly be worth the effort.

Comment: You're welcome @Nargis. When you have the opportunity, take a look at Android Studio. It's a great IDE for Android, and a great tool once you get used to it.

Comment: Thanks for suggestion @Lars , but I guess android studio does not support NDK Integration yet!

Comment: Yeah, you're right. I hope that the Eclipse plugin works out for you.